# OpenAPI parameter description vs parameter schema description

Tags: openapi

In OpenAPI 3.0, I'm wondering what the difference is when [describing parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/). For example, what is the difference between descriptions "Foo" and "Bar" below? Is the one for "Foo" more for the semantics of the parameter and the one for "Bar" more for the syntax, if that makes sense? Should just one be used generally (and which if so)?

```json
{
  "name": "someParameter",
  "in": "query",
  "description": "Foo",
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "Bar"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter description is specified by the `description` in the parameter itself.

It just so happens that parameters use a `schema` to define the data type, and schemas can have their own `description`. In the context of parameters, you can think of the schema-level `description` as the description of the parameter's *data type*.

The two descriptions are semantically separate. Schema-level `decription` is [NOT a fallback](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5089#issuecomment-448694627) for missing parameter `description`.

Here's another example:

```yaml
paths:
  /users/{id}:
    delete:
      summary: Delete a user
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          required: true
          description: The ID of the user you want to delete.
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
            description: >-
              A unique identifier in the format "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".
```

In practice, parameters usually don't have a schema-level `description` specified because it's often redundant.